# I want to know how to pass another parrameter in my forum view through this template url?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

this is my template file

```
<div id="list">
<table border="3px solid black" cellpadding="4" width ="100%">
    <tr>
        <td><div></div> </td>
        <td>Posts</td>
        <td>Last Post</td>
        <td><div></div> </td>
    </tr>

{% for forum in forums %}
<tr>
    <td {% if forloop.last %}class = "last"{% endif %}>
            <div class="title"> {{ forum.title }}
            </div>
    </td>
    <td {% if forloop.last %} class="last" {% endif %}>{{ forum.num_posts }} </td>
    <td {% if forloop.last %} class="last" {% endif %}>{{ forum.last_post.short|linebreaksbr }} </td>
    <td {% if forloop.last %} class="last" {% endif %}}> <a href="{% url 'frm.views.forum' %}"> VIEW </a> </td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

and this is a function in views.py

```
def forum(request,pk):
threads = Thread.objects.filter(forum=pk).order_by("-created")
threads = mk_paginator(request,threads,20)
return render_to_response("forum.html",add_csrf(request,threads=threads))
```

**I want to pass this extra parameter through template file .
How can I do that ?**

from urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from frm.views import main,forum

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',main),
    url(r'^forum/$',forum),
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'forum.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Like this `{% url 'frm.views.forum' forum.pk %}` ?

Comment: yes , but this is not working

Comment: show the urls.py file

Comment: I have updated with urls.py file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
url(r'^forum/$', forum)
```

to this, so that url pattern must accept one parameter which is id of forum:

```
url(r'^forum/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', forum)
```

and in `url` tag pass forum id:

```
{% url 'frm.views.forum' forum.pk %}
```